# Typesript argument depends on another argument with a default value

Tags: typescript, default-arguments, keyof

I am trying to make a function in typescript where the second, optional argument, is a key of the first argument. Without the optional argument, the function I want looks like

```js
function getVal<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

However, I would like `key` to be optional and take the default value of `"id"`. But, the function

```js
function getValBad<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T = "id") {
    return obj[key];
}
```

doesn't typecheck, since typescript doesn't know if `T` has a key of `id`. A partial fix to this problem is to write

```js
function getValOk<T extends { id: any }>(obj: T, key: keyof T = "id") {
    return obj[key];
}
```

however, this forces `T` to always have a key of `id`.

My question is, can I write a function `getValGood` so that `getValGood({id: 1})` typechecks, `getValGood({ID: 1}, "ID")` typechecks and `getValGood({ID: 1})` doesn't type check. If so, how do I represent `getValGood` in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll probably want to use another generic argument to type the returned value properly. (Otherwise, `obj[key]` will return a union of *all* possible values on the object, not *just* the type at `key`)

You can overload the `getVal` function to take either an object and a key that's a property of the object (2 generics), OR use only a single generic `{ id: V }` and return something of type V:

```
type GetVal = {
    <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K];
    <V>(obj: { id: V }): V;
};

const getVal: GetVal = (obj: Record<string, unknown>, key = 'id') => {
    return obj[key];
};

const result1 = getVal({ foo: 'foo' }, 'foo');
const result2 = getVal({ foo: 'foo' }, 'doesntexist'); // Fails

const result3 = getVal({ id: 'val' });
const result4 = getVal({ }); // Fails
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbKBeKBvAsAKCkKgB4AVAGigGkoIAPYCAOwBMBnKAawhAHsAzKKQB8ACl4AjAFYAuIZW4g5VAJRzSAbSoBdANz4iJBGMmzsUAJYs5CKAF81UBPrx2X+AMa8mbYFADm8MgocnCIqBhQ4tJyAEoQXgBOLMS+iRZM-pQArkycTLwA7kzCCjyRAORWFSoYwtgGRInw2YlMUKYainr4dvie3r5QzWzZKMAAjJGB4SiiWFD8vLxyFUu8FfaUa8s1Ll4+fiNjwABM00Go84vLq+ubdtssvBBsTIx0Fr57-XgHQ8dxgBmC6za5WVYAN1QDxU+0GR1eJwALKDgtcHLogA)

Comment: Yeah, I think overloads are about as good as it gets here. Your version might have some weird excess property issues if you call `getVal({id: "val", someOtherProp: 123})`, but that could be resolved [easily enough](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0EQN).  Trying to do this without overloads seems like a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use function overloads for this:

```js
function getVal<V>(obj: {id: V}): V;
function getVal<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K];

function getVal(obj: any, key = 'id') {
    return obj[key];
}
```

Note that when a function has overload signatures, Typescript does not check for you that the function implementation actually conforms to each overload signature individually; it's up to you to make sure that the implementation you write is type-safe according to the overload signatures.

Typescript will still at least make sure that each call to the function is correctly-typed.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2AeDAPgAo4AjAKwC5EBvGAExowF8BKZgbgChRJYEKdNnwAVADSIA0olQAPKKjAMAzogDWqAJ5xgiUSXLV9kzVppSO+gNpSAuj17ho8JGky5SlGljBbT2ogAvIgA5IyhbHTciLGIAE7oIPFIRtZmDtws3EA)